# Require both checkbox and dropdown

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a simple validation form where a Checkbox or a Select box value must be chosen, else a popup message is shown.  Pretty simple, but i'm messed up something small as i can't get it working.

```
if ((strUser == 0) && (getElementById("somename").checked == false)) 
    alertMsg += "\n- Donation Amount";
```

[Code Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xv87K/5/)

------------------------Update -----------------

After seeing part of my issue was in jsfiddle, i was able to narrow it down to get it working using this.  I also updated the link above to show a working example.

```
var strUser = +Donation.options[Donation.selectedIndex].value;
if ((strUser == 0) && (somename.checked == false)) alertMsg += "\n- Donation Amount";
```

Comment: Did you define the function `getElementById`? Or do you mean `document.getElementById`? The console should show an error if it is "not working".

Comment: Your fiddle gives the error `ReferenceError: validateForm is not defined` because the function is defined inside the `load` event handler, it is not global. I don't know if that's the issue you or not. Please provide more information. "It does not work" is not a useful error description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug is most likely here:

```
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

The value of this html element is a **string**, and all strings, other than the empty string, are truthy.

The simplest fix would be to convert that value to a number, so that you get the (falsy) number zero, rather than the string "0"

```
var strUser = +e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

Or of course just test the selected index directly

```
var strUser = e.selectedIndex;
```

Comment: @Felix - for sure.  He's got an un-needed with in there for starters.  But hey, we all start somewhere :)

Comment: i've used the 'with (document.form1)' because i pulled a few other text fields that I removed from the sample since they were working fine.  I know I should just use 'getElementById' for everything though but didn't because ... don't know why actually.  Old habit i guess.

Comment: instead of `with (document.form1) {` consider just using `var f = document.form1;`